# build keepalived rpm from its latest source

Tags: rpmbuild

I tried to build rpm from the latest keepalived (Version 2.0.7)

no issues during ./configure and make

But when executing

```
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /root/rpmbuild
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /root/rpmbuild/SPECS
[root@localhost ~]# cp keepalived-2.0.7.tar.gz /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
[root@localhost ~]# cp keepalived-2.0.7/keepalived.spec /root/rpmbuild/SPECS
[root@localhost ~]# rpmbuild -ba /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/keepalived.spec
error: line 30: Unknown tag: @WITH_REGEX@BuildRequires: pcre2-devel
```

pcre2-devel and pcre2 also have installed.

How can I fix this?

Thank you
Luke.

Comment: That looks like there's supposed to be a script run on the specfile first to replace some stuff, like that `@WITH_REGEX@`. I'd check if there is a top-level `make` target like `rpm` that the authors provided.

Comment: Keepalived release note says : Release 2.0.7

 Remove pcre build tests from Travis-CI
   Travis-CI environments are too old to support libpcre2, so we have
   to remove it.

But, it seems, still libpcre2 giving some issues. Please help us on this as the clients are expecting to be updated with the latest version.

Comment: Okay... as I said, it looks like they are trying to (optionally) remove that line with some script call that you're not doing.